# DynamicObject vs Dictionary performance, or faster?

Tags: c#, performance, dynamic, dictionary

I'm wondering if the DLR, or CLR does any kind of performance optimizations when making calls to a dynamicObject.

Given code similar to :

```
var dictionary = new dictionary<string,string>()
dictionary.add("hello","foo");
dynamic bag = new ..DynamicObject..
bag.hello = "foo";
//Are there any thread safety benefits, or performance differences between making
//many calls to :
var x = dictionary["hello"];
var y = bag.hello;
```

In DynamicObject I see stuff about binders and such, and wonder if those binders end up in improving performance or if they get invoked on every call and actually slow things down vs a dictionary?

Lastly, is there a quicker way to retrieve values by some kind of key or lookup than a dictionary? I'm not concerned about how long it takes to add items, only how long it takes to retrieve them. Even if its some kind of fancy expressionTree builder or something like creating a new expression tree with a switch statement in it every time a new item is added?

-- To explain why this is not pre-optimization --
Here is my profiling results.

```
Function Name   Inclusive Samples   Exclusive Samples   Inclusive Samples % Exclusive Samples % Module Name
Foo_Console.exe                                                 459 0   100.00  0.00    
    Foo_Console.Program.Main                                    459 0   100.00  0.00    Foo_Console.exe
        Foo.Program.BenchmarkSync                               443 3   96.51   0.65    Foo_Console.exe
            Foo.Calculate                                       404 53  88.02   11.55   Foo.dll
                Foo.DictionaryBag`1[System.__Canon].TryGetValue 343 51  74.73   11.11   Foo.dll
                    [mscorlib.ni.dll]                           235 235 51.20   51.20   mscorlib.ni.dll
                    [clr.dll]                                   57  57  12.42   12.42   clr.dll
```

and here is the implementation of the Foo.DictionaryBag'1.... call

```
type DictionaryBag<'TKey when 'TKey:equality> ()=
    let bag = ConcurrentDictionary<System.Type,IDictionary>()
    ... snip ...
    /// returns a tuple of (Found * 'TValue) where the Key = (key * typeof<'TValue>)
    member this.TryGetValue<'TValue> (key:'TKey) =
            let found, innerCollection = bag.TryGetValue(typeof<'TValue>)    
            if found then
                let ic = innerCollection :?> ConcurrentDictionary<'TKey,'TValue> // Cast as the type we know it has to be
                let f, o = ic.TryGetValue key           // try to pull value out of inner dictionary
                (f,o)                                   // return what we found
            else
                (false, Unchecked.defaultof<'TValue>)   // if we didn't have an inner collection, then return (false and default<T>)
```

.. So you can see the dictionary performance is an issue when 74% of the profiling time was spent in the above method.

Comment: A dynamic object will never be quicker than a dictionary. There are multiple dispatches that happen for a `dynamic` object to do what it needs to do. This is because it can be re-assigned to a different type completely between operations.

Comment: This sounds like pre-optimization.  Typically I worry about maintainability over performance because normally differences in speed you are suggesting are rarely an issue.

Comment: Sadly I pull values from my current dictionary over 20mil times a second. I really want to make sure there is no possible faster way in .net to fetch values that have been specified at runtime.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Updated question with section regarding pre-optimization

Comment: @AustinHarris According to MSDN, TryGetValue approaches O(1) so I don't see how you can improve on that.

Comment: @o_weisman well.. you can have two O(1) functions and have one be 2x as fast because the O(1) is a measure of how it scales by collection size, or successive calls. So i'm still looking for another o(1) solution that is any % faster then the built in one.

Comment: @AustinHarris You are of course correct, but how will you know that the answer you get is in fact better than the one you use without extensive benchmarking?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead that's not quite true. If the types and member names are static the DLR generates optimized code that does not need dictionary lookups at all. A little like modern JS engines do it.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I may be a little late to this question but I feel like your statement may be a bit misleading.  I ran into this http://spiritofdev.blogspot.com/2011/12/performance-of-c-40-dynamic-vs.html

Comment: @EasyE: Honestly I don't quite remember my exact thought process for my statement in 2014. There have been many advancements in the DLR and JIT compilers since then so I imagine my statement from 2014 may not hold as true. That said, I do find those results you've pasted from 2011 to be odd. The `ExpandoObject` faster than a `Dictionary` ? ...isn't an `ExpandoObject` basically a wrapper around a `Dictionary`? (Honestly I don't follow .NET internals that closely anymore)